# mongo php get records where last nested array is value

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb and php setup. The db has records which contain nested documents/array/objects

The objects is "history" and every time we update the record with a new review status, we save the review comment and history and reviewers name to the array. Essentially this means there could be 1,2,3,4... sub items in the array. I'm wanting to query where the last entry of the array is = to a certain status.

I want to select all records where the last arrHistory entry is 1

IE:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("58753dda41140663d00c7871"), 
"strName" : "Some Record",
"strContent" : "Something here", 
"arrHistory" : [
    {
        "strComment" : "Great entry",
        "bApproved": 1

    }
]
}


{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("58753dda41140663d00c7871"), 
"strName" : "Some New Record",
"strContent" : "Something here", 
"arrHistory" : [
    {
        "strComment" : "Bad story",
        "bApproved": 0

    },
    {
        "strComment" : "Thanks for fixing story",
        "bApproved": 1

    },
]
}

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("58753dda41140663d00c7871"), 
"strName" : "Some Older Record",
"strContent" : "Something here", 
"arrHistory" : [
    {
        "strComment" : "Bad story",
        "bApproved": 0

    },
    {
        "strComment" : "Still bad",
        "bApproved": 0

    },
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I your situation you can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in the first project stage to get the last element in the array (when you use a negative position the item is counted from the end of the array).

In the next stage find the documents where the bApproved is 1.

Below the example:

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    [
        {
            $project: {
            "_id" : 1,
            "strName" : 1,
            "strContent" : 1,
            "last_arr_history" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$arrHistory", -1 ] }     
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
            "last_arr_history.bApproved" : 1
            }
        },

    ]    
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`$redact`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** in your aggregation pipeline which allows you to proccess the logical condition with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses a single pipeline stage which is more efficient.

---

Consider the following example which demonstrate the above concept:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$anyElementTrue": {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": { "$slice": ["$arrHistory", -1] },
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": { 
                                "$eq": ["$$el.bApproved", 1] 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58773281894725fb3fd3f92a"),
    "strName" : "Some Record",
    "strContent" : "Something here",
    "arrHistory" : [ 
        {
            "strComment" : "Great entry",
            "bApproved" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58773281894725fb3fd3f92b"),
    "strName" : "Some New Record",
    "strContent" : "Something here",
    "arrHistory" : [ 
        {
            "strComment" : "Bad story",
            "bApproved" : 0.0
        }, 
        {
            "strComment" : "Thanks for fixing story",
            "bApproved" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

In the above example, the **[`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** combo works in such a way that the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator transforms arrays in place in the document by returning each inspected element evaluated by the given expression. It thus creates a new array which is only composed of the last element (via **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/#exp._S_slice)**) and if the element in the array actually has a `bApproved` value of 1, then this is a true match via **[`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/)** and the document is "kept". Otherwise it is "pruned" and discarded from the results.

---

The equivalent PHP example implementation:

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient("localhost");
$c = $m->selectDB("yourDbName")->selectCollection("yourCollectionName");
$pipeline = array(
    array( 
        '$redact' => array(
            '$cond' => array(
                array( 
                    '$anyElementTrue' => array(
                        '$map' => array(
                            'input' => array( '$slice' => array('$arrHistory', -1) ),
                            'as' => 'el',
                            'in' => array( 
                                '$eq' => array('$$el.bApproved', 1) 
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                '$$KEEP',
                '$$PRUNE'
            )
        )
    )
);
$results = $c->aggregate($pipeline);
var_dump($results);
?>
```